# How to create an observable array from a firestore DocumentReference array field

Tags: angular, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm structuring a firestore database to be used for e-commerce purposes. Currently I have a products root level collection and a users root level collection. The users collection has an array field named cart In which I'm storing Documentreferences to the products collection for each item in that users cart. I'm not sure of the best method to properly form an `Observable<Product[]>` from the DocumentReference array.

I currently have something that kind of works but I'm positive it's not the best way to do it and that it'll cause problems in the app. Especially because every time a component subscribes to this observable the service creates a new subscription for each item in the cart and those subscriptions are never unsubscribed from...

```js
// Current method from cart service

getItems(): Observable<Product[]> {
  return this.auth.user.pipe(
    map((user: User): Product[] => {
      this.items = [];
      user.cart.forEach((item: firestore.DocumentReference) => {
        this.afs.doc(item.path).valueChanges().pipe(
          map((product: Product) => {
            this.items.push(product);
          })
        ).subscribe();
      });
      return this.items;
    })
  );
}
```

I'd like to be able to query this field for the logged in user and return an `Observalbe<Product[]>` from the cart service that I can subscribe to and use to display the items in the users cart in a component. My knowledge and understanding of the rxjs library is fairly rudimentary and there's probably an operator that would do the job properly. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

To unsubsribe the `firestore` observable created in your `service`, try following

```
<!-- someName.component.ts -->
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';
```

In your component class

```
 private firestoreSubscription: Subscription;

/* Your method to get data from firestore service */
getCartData(){
this.firestoreSubscription = this.service.getItems()
.subsribe(data=>//your stuff);
}
```

And unsubscribe to this in `ngOnDestroy()` life cycle hook of `Angular`

```
ngOnDestroy(){
if (this.firestoreSubscription)
  this.firestoreSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I was just going to use the async pipe to unwrap the observable in my html. The problem is that those other subscriptions that are generated because I subscribed to the individual documents in the service still wont be unsubscribed from. What I'm kind of looking for is a better way to structure the getItems() method to where I don't have to subscribe in the service. I've been trying looking at mergeMap or combineLatest form rxjs but I'm still trying to figure out how to use them for my use case.